# webview inside onclick imagebutton error

Tags: android, webview, imagebutton

I am trying to open webview with an imagebutton. I was able to do with an intent and uri.parse like so:

```
        twbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("website"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
```

But it exits the application and opens the browser. I want it to open up without leaving the application

```
    fbbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_socialmedia, container, false);
            WebView myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
            myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            myWebView.loadUrl("website");


        }
    });
```

but I get the error:

```
W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
W/AwContents﹕ onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
```

Comment: Your `webview` is not being found in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to have the element `webview` inside the layout `fragment_socialmedia.xml` ?

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_socialmedia, container, false);
 WebView myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

thats the reason for what you are getting this exception : `android.webkit.WebSettings android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()' on a null object reference`

Comment: I still cannot get the webview to open up whatsoever. It just does nothing. I get the error listed above... IRT ignoring

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap these two lines:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("website");
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Set WebViewClient *before* doing the load:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
myWebView.loadUrl("website");
```

Comment: that didn't fix it. I tap on the button and nothing happens

Comment: I still cannot get the button to do anything. I have switched it, but nothing yet

Comment: @daybis13: So, does it just not doing anything, or does it still open the browser?

Comment: the application is not doing anything whatsoever. I just tap on the screen and nothing. the information I get from the log is the one mentioned above even with the fix you recommended